# getting data from database not working php

Tags: php, html, database

This is part of a small project that im working, in this page I getting info from a database, my question(problem) is why this line of code works.

```
echo '<td><a href="add.php?id=' .$row['id'] .'">' . htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</a></td>';
```

But this one don't work

```
<td><?php ' ' . htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ' ?> </td>
```

This is the entire code of the page

```
 <?php
    require("coneccion.php");
    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;



    $query = "SELECT id, name, due, points FROM grades WHERE id = '$id' ";

    try
    {
      $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
      die("Error 1" . $ex->getMessage() );
    }

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    ?>



    <br />
    <a href="add.php">Add</a>  

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Due</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach($rows as $row):
      echo "<tr>";
         echo '<td><a href="add.php?id=' .$row['id'] .'">' . htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</a></td>'; 
         ?> 
          <td><?php ' ' . htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ' ?> </td>
          </tr>
         <?php

         endforeach;
```

Comment: you need to fire a command which will allow php to generate an output like echo, print. <td><?php ' ' . htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ' ?> </td> can be corrected as <td><?php echo(htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); ?> </td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of::

```
<td><?php ' ' . htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ' ?> </td>
```

*try*

```
 <td><?php echo ' ' . htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' '; ?> </td>
```

Notice the `echo` statement in there, so we can output the content back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Because the characters **' ' .** cannot be interpreted by PHP without any command like echo.
If you look at the 2nd line like this it will be clear maybe:

```
<td>
<?php
    ' ' .    // PHP cannot parse this
    htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');    // PHP can parse this
    . ' '    // PHP cannot parse this
?>
</td>
```

The correct way would be:

```
<td>
<?php
    echo ' ';    // PHP cannot parse this
    echo htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');    // PHP can parse this
    echo ' ';    // PHP cannot parse this
?>
</td>
```

or

```
<td>
<?php echo ' '.htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').' '; ?>
</td>
```